# Why is the answer "ameliorate the impact" and not "attenuate the impact"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning

> Considering the consensus of the world's leading meteorologists that there will be a vastly greater number of natural calamities (such as hurricanes and floods) during the first several decades of the twenty-first century, some experts recommended that more developing countries should do what Bangladesh has done--build into their development plans strategies to _______ the impact of such disasters on development.
>
> a. ameliorate
> b. attenuate
> c. comprehend

The answer to the blank is ameliorate in the book [Barron's GRE Verbal Workbook, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143800379X)

I have heard many times phrases like to minimize impact, to soften impact etc. So, thought the answer should be to attenuate the impact.

Can you please explain why doesn't the word attenuate work here?

Comment: I agree with you (and not the book).  *Attenuate* makes sense in that context.  *Ameliorate* might sort of work, but it doesn't work well, and definitely not as well as *attenuate*.

Comment: @Juhasz: I think you are mistaken. Both ***attenuate*** and ***ameliorate*** are at least "credible" on semantic grounds, as you say. But if you check the last two links in my answer I think you'll have to agree that even though ***neither*** of them are in the "Top 10", ***ameliorate*** is in fact significantly more common than ***attenuate*** before (undesirable) ***impacts***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, were I writing or editing this piece, I also wouldn't have chosen any of those three options.  For a GRE question, where definitional precision is important, *attenuate* seemed to me like the better choice.  In my experience studying for this test, these kind of frustrating questions were fairly common.  Fortunately, they either didn't appear on the actual test, or else there were enough reasonable questions that my score wasn't seriously effected.

Comment: @Juhasz: Well, as [this NGram]() shows, ***ameliorate the impact*** is in fact twice as common as ***attenuate the impact*** - but obviously *both* those terms would practically "flatline" by comparison with more idiomatic alternatives such as ***reduce, minimise, mitigate, limit, lessen, alleviate, soften*** as flagged up in my answer. But if you think it's meaningful to say that ***attenuate*** is "the better choice" in the face of such evidence to the contrary ***and*** the fact that it's an irrelevancy anyway, I'm not gonna keep arguing the toss.

Comment: ...sorry - I meant [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attenuate+the+impact%2Cameliorate+the+impact&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattenuate%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cameliorate%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cattenuate%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cameliorate%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I think that one talks more of mitigation here than anything else. mitigate

Comment: We can't actually see that text with the link.

Comment: It's very possible that the answer KEY has an error. //We'd say: **ameliorate the impact of social programs on the society". BUT: **attenuate the impact of natural disasters on a community".

Answer (score 3):

See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=measures%20to%20*%20the%20impact&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cmeasures%20to%20%2A%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmeasures%20to%20reduce%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmeasures%20to%20cushion%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmeasures%20to%20assess%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmeasures%20to%20mitigate%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmeasures%20to%20minimize%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmeasures%20to%20lessen%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmeasures%20to%20limit%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmeasures%20to%20evaluate%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmeasures%20to%20soften%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmeasures%20to%20alleviate%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0) showing which words are most likely to occur in OP's context...

[image]

I wouldn't use ***attenuate*** here myself, and it doesn't appear in that "Top Ten" list.

---

BUT - nor do ***ameliorate*** or ***comprehend***. And they're a curious pair of alternatives, given that so far as I'm concerned ***attenuate*** and ***ameliorate*** are just two "equally sub-optimal" choices, whereas ***comprehend*** simply makes no sense whatsoever.

Anyone who chooses ***comprehend*** is unquestionably *wrong*, but I see no good reason for preferring [***ameliorate***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22measures%20to%20ameliorate%20the%20impact%22) over [***attenuate***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22measures%20to%20attenuate%20the%20impact%22) or vice-versa (those are links to many written instances of *both* terms). In short, the "test" is poorly-devised, so don't spend too much time analysing it.

Comment: It is most definitely attenuate here. This are AmE GREs and they give words that wouldn't work on purpose. The only one that works here is precisely attenuate so it doesn't matter about the ngrams. Google this: natural disasters and attenuate the impact, as in lessen  And the word is strategies, not measures. Of course, with measures attenuate won't work.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+attenuate+the+impact&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattenuate%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cattenuate%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I don't see the point of your comment or your chart link. The *important* chart is [***this one***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ameliorate+the+impact%2Cattenuate+the+impact&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3), showing that ***ameliorate** the impact* is far more common than ***attenuate** the impact*. The three choices offered by the test strike me as incredibly stupid. One doesn't work ***at all***, and neither of the other two are in the top ten for the context. But to suggest the *less* common of those two is "correct" makes no sense to me.

Comment: ... and "strategies" and "measures" are synonymous in this context, so that makes no difference.

Comment: You don't get it. This is a multiple choice Graduate Record Exam. There are three choices: comprehend, attenuate and ameliorate. There are no other choices. The choice does not include ameliorate. {Anyway, I fail to see how one can improve the impact of a disaster). So, to get a higher score, you have to say attenuate here.

Comment: And these are not measures. They are **strategies** to reduce the impact of a disaster. The reason the other two words are there are for you **not to choose them**.

Comment: I don't see the point of you repeatedly telling me that *you disagree with most other native Anglophones*, who have clearly shown that they're perfectly happy to refer to ***ameliorating the impact***. Your position may have some merit in terms of literal dictionary definitions, but at the end of the day, English is defined by how people use it, not what dictionaries and etymology would suggest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140191/discussion-between-lambie-and-fumblefingers).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Google hits, *ameliorate the impact* is most often used for metaphorical impacts, while *attenuate the impact* is usually used for actual physical impacts, when two objects collide. Since this is a metaphorical impact, and since the instructions are probably something like "choose the word that fits best", you can certainly argue that *ameliorate* is the correct answer.

However, using *attenuate the impact* for metaphorical situations is not that uncommon, and it is not ungrammatical or incorrect here.

Comment: The text is about natural disasters and there is nothing metaphorical about it. Also, attenuate or ameliorate here is about meaning, not grammar, which is irrelevant. Not part of the question.

Comment: @Lambie: A literal impact is when somebody who is driving a pick-up truck hits your VW, or when a large meteorite crashes into Mars, or a similar collision. The first definition in  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impact) is: an impinging or striking especially of one body against another. The first definition in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/impact):  the force or action of one object hitting another.

Comment: Yes, but here it's not about grammar. It's semantics. Because these are all transitive verbs. Also, something can be 100% grammatical and nonsensical i.e. be wrong or inaccurate semantically. Lewis Carroll's poetry is often nonsensical, never agrammatical.

Answer (score -3):

**GREs work like this: They give you multiple choice.**

Even if you think you have a better word, that is not the point.
The point is to pick a word from what they give you in order to get a point on the exam.

Of these three: a. ameliorate b. attenuate c. comprehend

The only right answer in this case is **attenuate**. **In the sense of lessen the impact of such disasters on development.**

attenuate means to lessen or make less serious. The other two are frankly silly.

The other two words make no sense. You cannot ameliorate an impact. Make it better??

And comprehending the impact is not what the sentence is about.

Since 1940 forward there is increasing usage of attenuate the impact in ngrams, which I do not know how to copy. Sorry.

GRE practice exams and even the exams have Answer Keys.
There is a list with the question number and a letter for the multiple choice. ***It is very possible that the answer key is showing the wrong answer.***

ameliorate the impact:
This spending has **ameliorated the impact** of these social programs on communities.

This program has **attenuated the impact** of the disaster on local populations.

Comment: I disagree entirely. Both "reduce the force of" and "make less bad" are reasonable senses, and I find a metaphorical sense of _attenuate_ rather odd. I definitely prefer _ameliorate_.

Comment: Also please see attenuate the impact of the disaster: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22attenuate+the+impact+of+the+disaster%22&ei=I75aY5ytM9iIptQP5Led2AI&ved=0ahUKEwjcyrn-9YD7AhVYhIkEHeRbBysQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22attenuate+the+impact+of+the+disaster%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAghEMMEEKABOggIABCiBBCwAzoFCCEQqwI6CgghEMMEEAoQoAFKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQpgZYwglgwAtoAXAAeACAAfcBiAGyBJIBBTIuMS4xmAEAoAEByAECwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz

Comment: @ColinFine It does not matter what you think or what I think. It matters what the creators of the **Graduate Record Exam** have in their heads. In a **multiple choice as given here, only attenuate will get you a point**.

Comment: Why on earth is *ameliorate* silly? It's even more common in [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ameliorate+the+impact%2C+attenuate+the+impact&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cameliorate%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattenuate%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0) than attenuate. And the dictionary definition of both words in English fits fine. (The French word *améliorer* and the Spanish word *mejorar* don't mean the same thing, and this may be confusing you; these are false friends.)

Comment: I agree that *améliorer l'impact* would be truly silly in French, but this is ELL.SE, not French.SE.

Comment: I thought we were here to help people *learn English*, not pass specific exams.

Comment: Um, @Lambie, the OP said "The answer to the blank is ameliorate in the book". I think that's a good answer, and you don't, but either way it is clearly not the case that "**only attenuate will get you a point.**"

Comment: @ColinFine Yep, apparently ameliorate will and I think it is a mistake myself: ameliorate a situation (improve) and attenuate an impact (lessen).

Comment: 19. ameliorate verb make better; improve; upgrade; alleviate; mitigate; assuage GRE Answer Key: https://wayzgoosepress.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/GRE-Answer-Key.pdf

Comment: @Lambie: What *ameliorate* usually means in English is *to make less bad*, so *alleviate, mitigate, assuage, palliate* are all good synonyms, but only rarely does it mean *improve* or *upgrade*.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you, I know exactly what it means. And frankly, I do not see **at all** how one can ameliorate the impact of a disaster on something. The impact of disasters can, however, be attenuated. **Finally, can't you and the others see that the exam proofreaders *failed to catch* this mistake?** The answer key says a) when it really should be b). Everybody is just going down the rabbit hole. People often fail to understand printing errors.